# ejb3 : JBAS014590: Unexpected Error

Tags: ejb, stateless-session-bean

trying to inject one stateless ejb bean into another stateless ejb bean. all stateless beans can inject successfully in flow. but for only one stateless ejb getting below error while loading.

JBAS014590: Unexpected Error

Comment: It would make sense to provide your code and stacktrace.

Comment: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:510)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:143)
        ... 358 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a39459f:5f09ac73:5a37c51c:980 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:352)
        ... 360 more

Comment: ... And put it into the question